# Running a basic script on a Google sheet without authorising

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

I have a font and alignment script which works like a charm on our daily spreadsheet.  However I copy the blank file (template) 30 ish times for each month.  As soon as I have done this, the font script stops working unless I go in and authorise it for each new sheet.  Is there any way, maybe with the script library i can run it automatically and not have to authorise each new sheet?  All users have edit access to the sheet.  I have been reading and playing with the script library but can't seem to get it to work at all.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to authorize a script and then not need to reauthorize a derivative of it, is to not create a derivative of it. Currently, you indicate the workflow is create a copy of yesterday's document, and then everyone works on the copy.

If you reverse the order, such that you archive the copy, then you will no longer need to continually reauthorize your script in a new file, as the working file contains an authorized Apps Script project.

1. Create a template file, which has the corresponding sheets you would like to start each day with
2. Write a script which will perform 2 tasks

   1. Export the current state of the active workbook to a new workbook (or even a PDF or other archive-ready asset)
   2. Replace the contents of the active workbook with those from the template workbook.
3. Run this script either manually or from a time-based trigger.